# SOC booting FPGA configuration file

Tags: fpga, embedded, sd, soc, system-on-chip

I have some understanding on embedded system booting process, which includes step wise execution of:

1. ROM boot loader.
2. First stage boot loader - internal to SOC.
3. Second stage boot loader - stored on RAM externally.

Starting from step 1, how the execution is ending in FPGA configuration means where the bit file information is stored when exported to HW file?

Comment: a system does not necessarily require all three stages

Comment: Is your question about a specific SOC device? If so, specifying the SOC device could help to get more informative answers.

Comment: In Xilinx (Zynq) devices, it is usually the first stage boot loader that also loads the FPGA configuration.